# javascript window.open function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to integrate paypal in a web site. For that paypal provides the JSP source code that the programers can use to listen to paypal IPN events, once you receive a IPN event, you do wathever you want with the information. In my case, what I am trying to do is just to insert a new js line to redirect the IPN information to a new webpage as shown shown next,

`<%@ page import= "java.util.*" %@>`
`<%@ page import= "java.net.*" %@>`
`<%@ page import= "javax.net.ssl.*" %@>`
`<%@ page import= "java.io.*" %@>`

`<%@`
`... paypal js source code`
`window.open("http://somesite.com?IPN_INFO"); // <--- new line inserted`
`... paypal js source code`
`%@>`

Problem is, whatever way I use to call the function "window.open", the tomcat server always responds back with the next error:

`...`
`The method window.open(String) is undefined for the type paypal_005fipn_jsp`
`62:                  String url = &quot;http://192.168.1.85:80?IPN_INFO&quot;;`
`63:                  window.open(url);`
`...`

I reallly would appreciate any feedback on this.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure by your example why you need to use JSP code to do this.  Just insert the JS code in the JSP by writing normal HTML and script tages.

The syntax <%@ is a directive in javascript.  It is used for things like page imports and includes.  What you want to do is use the following to insert some javascript into your page:

```
<%
System.out.println( "window.open(\"http://somesite.com?IPN_INFO\"); // <--- new line inserted );");
%>
```

You can also insert JSP variables like this:

```
window.open("http://somesite.com?IPN_INFO$var1=<%=someVariable%>");
```